# How come you can pass a Dataframe to pandas.plotting.autocorrelation_plot() when the function definition does not allow that?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

[The docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.autocorrelation_plot.html) explicitly state that the definition and parameters are:

```
pandas.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(series, ax=None, **kwargs)

seriesTime series
axMatplotlib axis object, optional
**kwargs
Options to pass to matplotlib plotting method.
```

So how come this doesnt result in an error, rather an actual plot?

```
d = {'col1': [1,2,4,3,2,2,1], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6,3,4,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(df)
```

Comment: This  might be an unintended side effect. Based on the source code, the Series is first converted to a numpy array before the rest of calculation: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ad190575aa75962d2d0eade2de81a5fe5a2e285b/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/misc.py#L449. Which happens  to work for both 1D  array and 2D array.

Comment: @Psidom But wouldnt the function definition require a series? 
def autocorrelation_plot(series: Series, ax: Axes | None = None, **kwds) -> Axes:
Edit: Actually, no it wouldnt. Thats not a type, just a variable. Im getting Java and Python mixed up.

Comment: Yeah, python doesn't do compile type check